# Angular: slow template refresh with async pipe when tab is in background

Tags: angular, pocketbase

In my Angular project, I have a component where I use `ngOnInit` to subscribe to a WebSocket. This subscription listens for any changes in a specific database table. When a change occurs, I fetch the updated data from the database and display it in my template. I'm using PocketBase to manage both the remote data and the WebSocket connection.

The problem is when the web application is left idle or is moved to a background tab. In such scenarios, even though I can see immediate network requests and responses for `getWaitingQueueEntries` and `getServingQueueEntries` (as verified through the browser's network development tool), the actual template takes significantly longer to update with the new data.

Interestingly, if I refresh the web page, the data updates almost instantly, but the problem recurs if I again put the page or tab in the background.

Here is the code:

```
waitingEntries$: Observable<QueueResponse[] | undefined> | undefined;
  servingEntries$: Observable<QueueResponse[] | undefined> | undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    // refresh the observables
    this.waitingEntries$ = this.backend.getWaitingQueueEntries(this.group!.id);
    this.servingEntries$ = this.backend.getServingQueueEntries(this.group!.id);
    // websocket subscription to any queue table changes
    this.backend
      .getPocketBaseInstance()!
      .collection(Collections.Queue)
      .subscribe('*', (update: RecordSubscription<QueueResponse>) => {
        if (update.record.group != this.group!.id) return;
        // refresh the observables
        this.waitingEntries$ = this.backend.getWaitingQueueEntries(this.group!.id);
        this.servingEntries$ = this.backend.getServingQueueEntries(this.group!.id);
        console.log('UPDATING');
      });
  }
```

Service:

```
  getServingQueueEntries(groupId: string): Observable<QueueResponse[] | undefined> {
    return this.getQueueEntries(groupId, 'serving');
  }

  getWaitingQueueEntries(groupId: string): Observable<QueueResponse[] | undefined> {
    return this.getQueueEntries(groupId, 'waiting');
  }

  getQueueEntries(groupId: string, status: string): Observable<QueueResponse[] | undefined> {
    return from(
      this.pocketBaseInstance
        ?.collection(Collections.Queue)
        .getFullList<QueueResponse>({
          filter: `group="${groupId}"&&status="${status}"`,
          sort: '-updated'
        })
    );
  }
```

Template:

```
  <div class="col-6 fw-bold text-secondary ps-4 bottom-dashes" *ngFor="let entry of waitingEntries$ | async">
    <div style="font-size: 5.5vw;">
      {{ formatNumber(entry.number) }}
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-12 fw-bold text-success ps-4 bottom-dashes" *ngFor="let entry of servingEntries$ | async">
    <div style="font-size: calc(1.525rem + 8vw); margin-top: -1.5rem;">
      {{ formatNumber(entry.number) }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: to not to change code much, just put `cdRef.detectChanges()` as the last line in subscribe. if it works, I'll describe what is not happening the right way here

Comment: @Andrei I have yet tried the `detectChanges()` and the same issue here, the only difference is that the layout become empty for a while and only then the data is updated (only after the idle), working fine if the page is fresh as described in the question.

Comment: @Andrei like [here](https://i.gyazo.com/f658d325526c4e69a629d7d7d6cc74aa.gif) you can see what is happening, I've changed the state of "002" and with `detectChanges()` the data in `*ngFor` just become empty - 10 seconds after I have changed the state, the UI has [been refreshed](https://i.gyazo.com/f4c0b2ec93ba0adee568ee258687b5a6.png)

Comment: I don't 100% understand the reason of your problem, but if you want I'll try to transform your code to something more error prone(more change detection friendly). there is a chance of it would help

Comment: what pocketbase library are you using?

Comment: @Andrei I would appreciate if you’d try to transform the code, I’m using the latest version of this [sdk](https://github.com/pocketbase/js-sdk)

Comment: @Andrei I believe I've identified and resolved the issue. It appears that the promises returned by PocketBase's functions are not registered within Angular's ngZone. Wrapping the client initialization in `ngZone.run()` seems to effectively address the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be linked to ngZone, it appears that the promises returned by PocketBase's functions are not registered within Angular's ngZone.

I've been able to resolve the issue by wrapping all the functions that return a `Promise` from the PocketBase with `ngZone.run`.

Like this in component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // refresh the observables
    this.getData();

    this.backend
      .getPocketBaseInstance()!
      .collection(Collections.Queue)
      .subscribe('*', (update: RecordSubscription<QueueResponse>) => {
        if (update.record.group != this.group!.id) return;
        // refresh the observables
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.getData();
        });
      });
  }

  getData() {
    this.backend.getWaitingQueueEntries(this.group!.id).then(data => {
      if (data) this.waitingEntries = data;
    });
    this.backend.getServingQueueEntries(this.group!.id).then(data => {
      if (data) this.servingEntries = data;
    });
  }
```

And in the service:

```
  getServingQueueEntries(groupId: string): Promise<QueueResponse[] | undefined> {
    return this.getQueueEntries(groupId, 'serving');
  }

  getWaitingQueueEntries(groupId: string): Promise<QueueResponse[] | undefined> {
    return this.getQueueEntries(groupId, 'waiting');
  }

  getQueueEntries(groupId: string, status: string): Promise<QueueResponse[] | undefined> {
    return this.pb
        ?.collection(Collections.Queue)
        .getFullList<QueueResponse>({
          filter: `group="${groupId}"&&status="${status}"`,
          sort: '-updated'
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When an Angular application is in a background tab or the browser is minimized, the change detection mechanism slows down to conserve resources.
however you can do it manually

inject ChangeDetectorRef

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, private backend: BackendService) {}
```

trigger change detection

```
this.backend
   .getPocketBaseInstance()!
   .collection(Collections.Queue)
   .subscribe('*', (update: RecordSubscription<QueueResponse>) => {
     if (update.record.group != this.group!.id) return;
     // refresh the observables
     this.waitingEntries$ = this.backend.getWaitingQueueEntries(this.group!.id);
     this.servingEntries$ = this.backend.getServingQueueEntries(this.group!.id);
     console.log('UPDATING');

     // Manually trigger change detection
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
   });
```

if that will not help take a look at NgZone

Comment: As I’ve mentioned in the comments forcing the ‘detectChanges’ does not solve the issue, it’s even not important to do it in the background, but here the issue is that it still slow even when the tab is resumed